# ¿Cambiar valor de una propiedad en un array TS?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola Tengo un proyecto En Angular, ya tengo almacenado en una variable el siguiente array, lo que sucede es que por ejemplo en la propiedad "estado" me puede enviar back end con el valor"A" o "I", en el código de ejemplo coloco "A", lo que busco es por ejemplo si me mandan en "estado" el valor "A", yo poder convertirlo a "Activo" o si me mandan "I" , yo convertirlo a "Inactivo", para yo poder mostrarlo asi en front end.

```
data = [{"estado" : "A" , "sexo" : "M"}]
```

Comment: Cómo estas mostrando ese arreglo en el front? Podrías incluir el código de tu HTML?

Comment: No se porque no me esta permitiendo adjuntar la imágen , pero te explico por aqui, tengo un componente independiente que es una tabla , esa tabla lo estoy colocando en el html de otro componente para usarlo allí, ahora para mostrar el cuerpo de ese array coloco [bodies]="data" , ahi en "data" es donde tengo el array, lo muestro tal cual .

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar lo que has intentado al momento a modo de [mcve]? Según veo, no debería existir mayor problema con lo que intentas lograr.

Answer (score 1):

Mi experiencia utilizando `Angular` no es muy amplia, pero lo que necesitas se puede realizar mediante `JavaScript`.

```
const newData = data.map((x:any) => ({
   estado: x.estado === 'A' ? 'Activo' : 'Inactivo',
   //otras props...
}))
```

Mediante la función **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**, puedes entregar un arreglo con la estructura y valores que necesites.

Ahora, si necesitas manejar más de 2 datos, podrías resolverlo concatenando el if ternario

```
const newData = data.map((x:any) => ({
   estado: x.estado === 'A' ? 'Activo' : x.estado === 'I' ? 'Inactivo' 
   : x.estado === 'D' ? 'otro valor' : 'valor por defecto'
}))
```

Después sería simplemente referencias ese nuevo arreglo (newData) en tu front.

Nos comentas si te sirvió :)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, una pregunta en el caso que tenga que evaluar 3 posibles valores como podria hacerlo? porque la respuesta que me brindas encaja perfecto para el caso de dos valores que formulo inicialmente, pero por ejemplo si en estado me mandan "A" "I" "D", ahi creo que cambiaria un poco "A" de activo , I de Inactivo y D de desabilitado

Comment: @Miky Editada!!

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la respuesta!